# Trouble formatting with titlesec and multicol

Tags: formatting, titlesec, multicol

I'm creating making resume with LaTeX, but I am having trouble with `multicol`. The following code reproduces the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackagae{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicols}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.5in]

\item Item 1
\item Item 2 
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item[\vspace{\fill}]

\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document
```

The output is this:

[image]

As you can see, Item 4 is on the same line as the subsubsection title. I have noticed that when I remove the `runin` optional argument, the problem is fixed. However, I need it for other subsubsections. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's the last item for?

Comment: I was looking around here and I saw an answer about how `multicol` will mess up the spacing between items. The last item fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll obtain what you want adding `\leavevmode` just after`\subsubsection' and removing the empty item:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}\leavevmode

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.5in]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3 
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You asked explicitely for a `runin` subsection, which means what `runin` means. Just remove this option and you get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}%[runin]
{\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.5in]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]